# Static Class in place of Oracle Table how to

Tags: java, oracle

I have an exotic question here.

Our Software Architect request us to remove an oracle table and substitute  it with a Static Java Class. This will be done for Performance reasons because that table will be touched 1 or 2 times every 5 years.

I never do in my life such a thing so witch is the best and elegant way to represent an oracle table with lot of rows using only Java ?

Comment: Could it be, you don't agree with the decision ;-)

Comment: I do not agree, but I'm not the boss, so I have to obey also questionable orders :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll omit the usual discussion on the why and I fully agree with you in that this design is at least questionable.

However, for the problem itself I'll try and suggest a simple suggestion without knowing your exact requirements: you might be able to create a singleton map and "generate" the put statements using a select statement, then copy and paste the result into your prepared class.

Something like this:

```
public class TableReplacement {
   private static Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

   static { 
     //put statements go here
   }

   ... //code needed to access the map
}
```

Next you issue a statement like this:

```
SELECT 'map.put("' || keyColumn || '","' || valueColumn || '");' FROM table;
```

which should generate results like this:

```
map.put("key1","value1");
map.put("key2","value2");
...
```

Then copy and past the result to your enum:

```
public class TableReplacement {
   private static Map<String, String> map;

   static { 
     map.put("key1","value1");
     map.put("key2","value2");
     ...
   }

   ... //code needed to access the map
}
```

Note that this would be a quick and dirty solution to "convert" a table to static code but this is clearly questionable.

How you define that map and the code to access the values depends on your exact requirements.

Comment: Funny coincidence: my software architect's name is Thomas

Comment: @velteyn But I'm not him ;)